# Как справиться с MemoryError?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Случилась довольно странная ситуация, у меня есть бот ВКонтакте который недавно переехал на новый хостинг. На старом хостинге таких ситуаций не возникало - на новом, я ограничен администратором в 512 МБ ОЗУ и 512 на подкачке. Поначалу, он работал вполне себе нормально, и тут внезапно начал сыпать `MemoryError`'ами. Казалось бы, я близко к решению, но нет! Я посмотрел в `htop`, там показывается что процесс потребляет далеко не всю память - всего лишь ~8 МБ.
Есть ли какой-нибудь способ обойти это исключение? Или я в чём то виноват?

ОС на сервере: Fedora 32
Версия Python: 3.7
Проблема появилась при добавлении новых модулей.

Comment: попробуйте сделать [memoryt profiling](https://pypi.org/project/memory-profiler),  чтобы найти самое затратное место

Comment: Также мне известно, что это вызвано тем, что интерпретатор не хочет злоупотреблять памятью. А я хочу дать ему полную власть, можно ли это реализовать как нибудь ?

Comment: Ну, посмотрите, какой именно код выбрасывает это исключение и что конкретно он делает — видимо, пытается захапать сильно больше восьми мегабайт

Comment: Error: Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<string>", line 15, in <module>

File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

File "/home/catpy/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/lyricsgenius/api.py", line 276, in search_song
lyrics = self._scrape_song_lyrics_from_url(song_info['url'])

File "/home/catpy/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/lyricsgenius/api.py", line 168, in _scrape_song_lyrics_from_url
html = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")

File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 861, in text
content = str(self.content, encoding, errors='replace')